# How to set client name and referrer in the Post WebRequest in C#?

Tags: c#, webrequest

How to set client name and referrer in the Post [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too sure about Client Name, but for Referer, you can use the [Headers property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers.aspx) to add these info.

See the [WebHeaderCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webheadercollection.aspx) for more information and example of header types.

You can consider using HttpWebRequest with the [Referer Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.referer.aspx) and others as well.

Comment: I guess "User-Agent" would work for the client name in the Headers.

Comment: I see, sounds like UA is the closest then. Good luck!